# Set multiple keys on firebase database using js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I need to create a more complex DB on my firebase project, and while I can create this DB on firebase console I cant do that using js.

```
database.ref('fcmTokens8').child('Users').child(firebaseUser.uid).set(
                        {
                            TIME: timeDate,
                            SUB: false
                        }
                    );
```

This is my code and works fine as it is but I need the "SUB" to have some additional IDs like "TOKEN" and "STATUS". How should I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
database.ref('fcmTokens8').child('Users').child(firebaseUser.uid).set(
                        {
                            TIME: timeDate,
                            SUB: {
                                    TEMP: "1",
                                    TEMP2: "2"
                                 }
                        }
                    );
```